# Factoring of a Pro-$\mathcal{C}$ morphism

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, $X$ an object of $\mathcal{C}$, and $p:I^{\circ}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ a projective system in $\mathcal{C}$.
Let $\alpha\in \mathrm{Mor}_{Pro(\mathcal{C})}(p,X)$, where $X$ is identified with the constant projective system of $X$. Can $\alpha$ factor through $p \rightarrow p(i) \rightarrow X$ for some $i\in I^{\circ}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more-or-less built into the definition of $\mathbf{Pro}(\mathcal{C})$. Recall that, given inverse systems $A$ and $B$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have
$$\mathrm{Hom}(A, B) = \mathop{\varprojlim_j} \mathop{\varinjlim_i} \mathrm{Hom}(A i, B j)$$ 
and so if $B$ is an inverse system indexed by the trivial diagram, then a morphism $A \to B$ necessarily factors through one of the projections $A \to A i$. The formally dual statement is true for $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor knowledge. Can you explain it in some concrete categories, such as the category of sets or modules in a constuctive way? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What is there to explain? I am just using the definition of morphsim in $\mathbf{Pro}(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: I mean the part of factoring, I just don't know why does it necessary factor through one of the projections.

Comment: Well, take a morphism $A \to B$. Then it has components $A \to B j$ (this is the ${\varprojlim}_j$ part) and each of those factors through some projection (this is the ${\varinjlim}_i$ part).